# Are there some clipboard managers for Windows 7 that I can configure so the clipboard history window stay on top?

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, ditto

I would like to have a clipboard manager for Windows 7 that I can configure so the clipboard history window stay on top.

E.g. with [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/), the clipboard history window looks like this (but [AFAIK](https://superuser.com/q/706146/116475) doesn't stay visible):

[image]

The motivation is that I use voice commands to paste previous clipboards, and I don't want to first have to display the clipboard history window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditto has an "Always on top" option.  Go under Right Click -> Quick Options-> Always on Top.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was looking under options, I didn't see the other quick options menu.